# Prevent variable from being scraped on webpage

Tags: javascript, regex, xpath

Let's say you have a javascript with a variable like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
...some javascript...
var secret = 123;
...some javascript...
</script>
```

Assuming you're able to write this javascript on the server side. Is it possible to prevent it from being scraped using regular expressions or Xpath?

I'm already changing the variable name on the server side to a random variable name.

The goal here is not to defeat a human taking the time to digest my code and make amendments on the client side (I know I can't stop this). It's more to make it hard/impossible for automated scripts to grab variables. Humans, given enough time, are better at scraping code than machines.

Comment: You can wrap your code in a function and then call it: `(function(secret) { .. do stuff with secret here .. })(123); console.log(secret); // cannot access secret here!`

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt/decrypt the value securely on the server-side?  That way you just pass around the encrypted value, which should be useless to anyone who can grab it from JS.

Comment: @JosephGabriel in this case it's something that is needed on the client side. But I don't want naughty people writing plugins to change the behaviour of my website.

Comment: @AmyNeville Don't use hypotheticals, it doesn't help to understand your situation. What are you trying to achieve and in what context? Without knowing, there are too many possible answers to your question.

Comment: @AmyNeville unfortunately, it's really not possible to prevent someone from tampering with your JavaScript code.  As Sebastien suggested, explain the problem a bit more, and maybe someone can help with a practical solution.  Proper obfuscation is a good start.

Comment: I know that it's not possible to prevent them tampering. What I am talking about is disrupting of automated tampering. Scripts that scrape for a variable and then use it to do naughty things. If I can make the code hard enough to read using regex etc then I can prevent this.

Comment: If you need to secure your client side code, your best bet is to not write those variables to the client side at all, and instead communicate with authenticated web service calls. That way you can keep your sensitive variables on the server side and pull their values only when you need them.

Comment: Yeah, I could AJAX them but that's more http requests which brings more overheads to my business. I'd rather just give them the run around on the client side :)

Comment: Your question would benefit from some context. Per my answer, it depends how much motivation you have to hide it (to protect from casual scripters, to make it difficult for someone with firebug, or to defend against someone writing privileged chrome/browser scripts, or someone willing to work with raw http requests) compared to how much motivation someone might have for getting/tampering with values (e.g. manipulating financial transactions, gaining advantages in a game for example).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The slightly longer answer is that the variable's value will always be transmitted in plaintext to the browser and, therefore, can always be scraped from the JavaScript because it will be declared (or used) in a predictable* manner.

The only bit you, as a creator, can control is making it difficult to programmatically extract. This might be by changing the location and form of the value/secret on every page load in a random manner, making any tokens single-use only, and by encrypting/encoding* things.

This doesn't **prevent** access to the secret, just makes it **less easy** to do, and by how much depends on the level of access the user has to the browser. Once you accept this, it boils down to a cost/benefit analysis of how much effort you want to put into this compared to the benefit.

*If the value is encoded in some way, there will be a decoding function within the JavaScript, enabling the encoded variable to be passed into the decoding function. Or perhaps any  functions can be replaced. For further reading, have a look into the very few attempts at encryption/decryption in JavaScript.